Spying on super class methods in Angular Unit Test with Jasmine/Karma
I am writing unit tests for an Angular component class that extends DualListComponent. The subclass, CustomDualListComponent, has a method onClickElement that calls a couple of super class methods selectItem and shiftClick:
onClickElement(disabled, item, confirmed, event, idx) {
  if (disabled || this.isLocked(item)) {
    return;
  }
  super.selectItem(confirmed.pick, item);
  super.shiftClick(event, idx, confirmed, item);
}

I want to test this method by verifying that selectItem and shiftClick methods get called with correct parameters. In my Jasmine test file, I tried to spy on these methods like:
const selectItemSpy = spyOn(CustomDualListComponent.prototype, 'selectItem');
const shiftClickSpy = spyOn(CustomDualListComponent.prototype, 'shiftClick');

// Call onClickElement method

expect(selectItemSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(shiftClickSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

However, my tests fail with "Expected spy selectItem to have been called. But it was never called." error. I suspect this is due to super keyword which directly accesses methods in the superclass and bypasses any in the subclass.
I understand that a typical advice would be to refactor onClickElement to use this instead of super but due to certain constraints, I am unable to modify the actual component's code. Is there a way to successfully spy on these super class methods called with super keyword in the method of the subclass?
Thank you in advance for your help.

I think this should work. You do have a couple of conditions there, so have you verified - with console.log, or otherwise - that the methods are indeed called?
